# Asp.Net Mvc 4 - Login does not work in Safari Mobile

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wordpress, asp.net-mvc-4, iframe

The design of my application is done with wordpress, but the login part I use an Iframe for the application Asp.Net Mvc 4 using window.open ('http://www.test.com.br/test/' '_top ') to login. I can not log into Safari Mobile, but in other browsers I can. I've tried to do:

```
<authentication  mode = "Forms" > 

 <forms  loginUrl = "~/Login"  timeout = "2880"  cookieless = "UseCookies" /> 

</authentication>
```

But I could not, in the url seems the page that comes after login, but the page that appears is the login, can not pass the login page.

I do not know if it's because the session or Iframe?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this problem is to apply you wordpress site in your MVC application. i.e. Download your wordpress site, and try to apply it in your MVC.